# SELECT colum containing values >1000

Tags: sql

I am using a SQL query

```
select 
    datediff(hour,Convert(DateTime,Convert(DateTime, Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)) + '' +  
    Convert(varchar,complainttime,114)),dateadd(mi,330,GETUTCDATE())) 
from complaintregister
```

It creates a column like

```
No column name
  15455
  15259
  15190
  15190
  15165
   300
   200
  1000
   500
```

and I want a column containg values > 1000

Comment: what c# and asp tags doing here?

Answer (score 5):

Just repeat the expression in the condition:

```
select datediff(hour,Convert(DateTime,Convert(DateTime, Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)) +''+  Convert(varchar,complainttime,114)),dateadd(mi,330,GETUTCDATE()))
from complaintregister
where datediff(hour,Convert(DateTime,Convert(DateTime, Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)) +''+  Convert(varchar,complainttime,114)),dateadd(mi,330,GETUTCDATE())) > 1000
```

The query planner should recognise that the expressions are identical and actually only calcuate it once for each record.

Alternatively you can use a nested query:

```
select time
from (
  select datediff(hour,Convert(DateTime,Convert(DateTime, Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)) +''+  Convert(varchar,complainttime,114)),dateadd(mi,330,GETUTCDATE())) as time
  from complaintregister
) x
where time > 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL server, you could dot something like this

```
    select tablename.colname from 
(select datediff(hour,Convert(DateTime,Convert(DateTime, Convert(nVarChar, cast(complaintdate as datetime), 101)) +''+  Convert(varchar,complainttime,114)),dateadd(mi,330,GETUTCDATE())) as colname
from complaintregister) as tablename
where tablename.colname > 1000
```

Don't have a test db atm, so you have to play around with it a bit